# $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"] not working? alternative?

Tags: php

This is odd, but for some reason the `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]` will not return the domain name when I am in child/sub-pages but will only work on the main page. Not sure if its due to the script (WordPress) or host, but please can you suggest any reliable solution to retrieve the domain name with PHP?

Comment: You may have been thinking of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: @Kzqai `SCRIPT_URI` is documented in the Apache docs as [an environment variable maintained by mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#EnvVar) - so from that it _should_ be present in the `$_SERVER` superglobal. However, as the OP has found, it's not always set (for whatever reason).

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292200/6293856

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you need domain name, use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Comment: Oh, this one worked fine!! even with url rewriting on. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

When in doubt

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you want, I'd use one of the following:

1. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for the script file location
2. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] for the host name

[From the php docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

EDIT: Maybe PHP_SELF isn't the best. See comments.

Comment: You should probably use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead of PHP_SELF.

Answer (score 5):

This might be due to URL rewriting, you can try $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead if you want the path that was called in the url.

Comment: If you do choose this method, be aware that it can be affected by the request headers.

Comment: Indeed. Theres url rewriting. But I do not want the path, I just want to check the domain name. Any way around?

Answer (score 2):

I was using $_SERVER[SCRIPT_URI] on my website 
http://www.a2zidx.com
and a number of subdirectories like
http://howto.a2zidx.com

I have had no problem with this for years and today got an error on a number of sites where $_SERVER[SCRIPT_URI] was not assigned. After contacting my isp they claim they have not made any changes but $_SERVER[SCRIPT_URI] no longer works. getenv('SCRIPT_URI') does not fail but returns a null string. Why this should happen suddenly after so many years I do not know. I ended up calling a function to go through various options to extract the filename which is what I wanted. Hope this covers everything. I had trouble including the function but checked 
"SCRIPT_NAME"
"PHP_SELF"
"SCRIPT_FILENAME
"SCRIPT_URI"

Hope his helps.

If anyone knows why SCRIPT_URI would suddenly stop working I would love to know. The server is currently running Apache 2.4.

Comment: The links look a lot like spam, please consider replacing them for generic ones like example.com

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($_SERVER)` and see what suites your needs.

*P.S. Making use of unsanitized `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` could be a [security risk](http://google.com/search?q=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']%20security%20risk).*

Answer (score 1):

Also, SCRIPT_URI does not exist, the right syntax is REQUEST_URI:

`echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` It returns the whole path without the host and domain.

Comment: `SCRIPT_URI` is not necessarily wrong. It is documented in the Apache docs as [an environment variable maintained by mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#EnvVar). However, as the OP has found, it's not always set (for whatever reason). But... when it is set, it's not the same as `REQUEST_URI`. `SCRIPT_URI` contains an _absolute URL_, whereas `REQUEST_URI` is a root-relative URL ("without the host and domain").

Answer (score 1):

Late late reply. I use this piece of script to store information in my db. Hope this might help someone. How to get your full url and the ip address of the client access from.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

echo $ip;
echo "<br>";
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

On Apache, SCRIPT_URI only exists when mod_rewrite is enabled.

Apache requires:

> rewrite_module (note: use platform specific load syntax)

and

> RewriteEngine On

statements in the Apache configuration file at the appropriate locations.

Then restart Apache, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

`SCRIPT_URI` is not fond because it has no any value when your site run with root domain. it only come when you working with sub-directory.

`HTTP_HOST` is not good idea when we working with sub-directory
use following code to get `SCRIPT_URI` :

```
$SCRIPT_URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.ltrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']),'/');
```

Comment: If HTTP request forwarded by proxy, the REQUEST_SCHEME may return "http" even if original request was made by secure https:// protocol. Check $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] additionally and use it instead of REQUEST_SCHEME if request was forwarded.

Answer (score -3):

If your browser formats `JSON` documents nicely and no output has taken place, inserting the following will result in something more readable than `var_dump`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');die(json_encode($_SERVER));
```

`phpinfo()` will also provide a list of all `$_SERVER` values and so much more!