# How to retrieve the URL of a page using PHP?

Tags: php, url

Newbie question here, is there any inbuilt PHP tag that can be used to retrieve the URL of a page and echo it on the screen?

Thanks.

Comment: Which page? The current one (i.e., the one being generated by the PHP script itself)?

Comment: This is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079457/www-to-non-www-redirect-with-php/2079463#2079463 . And look, I used the same function to answer it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echos the URL of the current page.

```
$pageURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
{
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} 
else 
{
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
echo $pageURL;
```

Comment: +1 very conscise. @OP: You can see all server variables that are available to you (Port, various URIs, request headers and languages, etc.) Using `print_r($_SERVER);` and viewing the output's source code.

Comment: It's actually the code that Google uses to find their page url.

Comment: Thanks Chacha, this works. I thought there might be some inbuilt tag similar to php_info since this seems like a very standard task but apparently not.

Comment: If `$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on"`, I believe you can use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]` and get the whole thing. Or is that just with Apache?

Comment: Someone on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717874/serverscripturi-not-working-alternative had problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

If your web server runs on standard ports (80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS) this would work:

```
getservbyport($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], 'tcp') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [$_Server](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable. Specifically you probably want the `REQUEST_URI` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_url = _SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$url_path = _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

echo $base_url.$url_path;
```

Assuming the requested page was `http://sample.org/test.php`, you would get:

```
 sample.org/test.php
```

You would have to add more $_SERVER variables to get the scheme (`http://`). `REQUEST_URI` also leaves any `GET` variables intact, so if the page request was `http://sample.org/test.php?stuff=junk`, you would get:

```
 sample.org/test.php?stuff=junk
```

If you wanted that left off, use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of `REQUEST_URI`.

If you want a really easy way to see which global variables are available, create a page with the following:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

and put that script in any directory you are curious about. Not only will you see all sorts of neat info, you will also see how various factors such as `HTTP` vs `HTTPS`, `mod_rewrite`, and even Apache vs IIS can set some global variables differently or not at all.